# AWS DynamoDB Scan Operation ScanFilter Not Working

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am running below dynamo DB scan query in AWS

```
const dynamoDb = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb.js');
const dynmoDBClient = new dynamoDb.DocumentClient({ region: "REGION"});
let params = {
   "TableName":"Users",
   "ScanFilter":{
      "name":{
         "AttributeValueList":[
            {
               "S":""
            }
         ],
         "ComparisonOperator":"GT"
      }
   },
   "Select":"ALL_ATTRIBUTES"
}


let result = null;
result = await dynmoDBClient.scan(params).promise();
```

When I run the query , I get below error -

```
ERROR occurred while querying data from DB : 
{"message":"One or more parameter values were invalid:
 ComparisonOperator GT is not valid for M AttributeValue type"}
```

As per table definition , name attribute is of type `S (string)` and not `M (map)`

But I am still getting this error.

Can anybody please help here as I am not getting what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 1):

AWS maintains sample code of core DynamoDB operations in various languages. Here's their sample for Scan in Node.js:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/node.js/WorkingWithScans/scan-parallel-segments.js

`ScanFilter` is legacy so don't go there.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.ScanFilter.html

Comment: :Thank you so much . Do you have any idea about injection attacks in dynamo DB . The above example is one sunch attack

Comment: It actually isn’t. There’s variable substitution happening that prevents such string boundary confusion. If you think there is an attack possibility there, please provide an example that shows the injection attack.